# Android view layout_width - how to change programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my view, and I wish to change layout_width to "10dip". How do I do so programmatically?
Note, this is not a LinearLayout, it's a View.

```
<View 
    android:id="@+id/nutrition_bar_filled" 
    android:background="@drawable/green_rectangle" 
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"/>
```

I know about LayoutParams. How do I use it to set the width to 10dip?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I believe your question is to change only width of view dynamically, whereas above methods will change layout properties completely to new one, so I suggest to getLayoutParams() from view first, then set width on layoutParams, and finally set layoutParams to the view, so following below steps to do the same.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled);
LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = newWidth;
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: You can also just do "view_instance.getLayoutParams().width = newOne;"

Comment: to get values like `match_parent`, this works: `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`

Comment: @snayde I believe setting the width and height parameters of the View's LayoutParams causes it to be remeasured and laid out

Comment: @TonyWickham looked at the View class implementation, didn't get how it does that :(

Answer (score 13):

Or simply:

```
view.getLayoutParams().width = 400;
view.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 10):

try using

```
View view_instance = (View)findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled);
view_instance.setWidth(10);
```

use [Layoutparams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)  to do so where you can set width and height like below.

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(10,LayoutParams.wrap_content);
View_instance.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: can you clarify? I'm almost ready to mark you as right answer. How do I get view_instance?

Comment: @Hisoka use `findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled)` to get the view

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. Seemed very intuitive, yet setWidth is not a valid function for a view.  View filledBar = rowView.findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled); filledBar.setWidth(10) <-- not valid.

Comment: The method setWidth(int) is undefined for the type 
 View

Comment: Ok, I refined my question. I already know about Layout params. My question is how do I use Layout Params to set the width of my View to "10dip". Reading the documentation online, it's not so obvious to me.

Answer (score 4):

androidx (`core-ktx`) contains an extension function to update layout params, for example:

```
view.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
    width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    // or wrap_content
    width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    // or size measured in pixels
    width = 200 
}
```