# Android videoview with expand and collapse

Tags: android, android-videoview

Now I am working on an Android application. In my app I have to play a video in the corner of the screen.I just play the video using videoview.

```
 Uri uri =       Uri.parse(path);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();
```

My requirment is  I have to expand the video in to full screen when clicking on the expand button like IPhone.ANd we have to collapse in to the old screen by clicking collapse button. In IPhone it is a default property. How can I achieve that in android?

For example..first time I am showing the video in a layout with other views . Then If I click the expand button on  videoview I have see the video in full screen also I can collpse back to the original screen.

My doubts are.
1) add expand button to the videoview
2) change size of the videoview from fixed size to fullscreen

Comment: You have to change the width and height of the VideoView control programatically upon event triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :

```
VideoView view_instance = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled);
LayoutParams params=view_instance.getLayoutParams();
params.width=newOne;
params.height=newOne;
view_instance.setLayoutParams(params);
```

referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159372/android-view-layout-width-how-to-change-programmatically)

Comment: Edited my question. please check

Comment: Yes you need to set the video view height and width to match_parent so the control will take full screen if it is directly placed on the parent layout.

Comment: @JibranKhan  how will i define width and height if my videoview parent is inside relativelayout

Comment: @Erum you will have to apply `setLayoutParams` to parent and parent's parent also if you want to alter their width height as well

Comment: @JibranKhan http://pastie.org/10423424 here is my layout file  ? what should i need to add code but my min api level is 16 so i cant follow this question ?and how can i  add another layout if my orientation is horizontal ?

Comment: @Erum what you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: @Erum so you actually need to make it fullscreen on landscape and compress it on portrait ?

Comment: Yes how will I do @Jibran khan

Comment: @Erum You can change width and height of the video or its relative layout by listening to orientation change event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android

Comment: answer above will do it after you successfully listen to orientation change

Comment: @JibranKhan  actually i have made custom layout for portrait and in portait i have viewpager and tabs below videoview now i lancape i dnt want viewpager but more buttons on top of video that is not present in portrait mode so mayi  need to inflate anotehr layout for lanscape once orentation change ?