# Android layout: Make RadioGroup occupy screen width next to a square ImageView

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/MyTabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton ... />

        <RadioButton ... />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SquareImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the code for the SquareImageView:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
   public SquareImageView(Context context) {
     super(context);
   }

   public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
   }

   public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
     int size = getMeasuredHeight();//Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
     setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
   }
}
```

Now, what I want to achieve is this:

[image]

I want the RadioGroup to occupy as much space as possible. The height of the LinearLayout should adapt to the required height of the RadioGroup. Each RadioButton should occupy 50% of the RadioGroup. The SquareImageView should adapt it's height to match the height of the LinearLayout, and it's width should also adapt to make it square.

Is this even possible?

The RadioGroup is no problem on it's own, but the tricky part is the square ImageView because I cannot get it to adapt it's width automatically. It is square, but I need to set the width of it manually. If I do not set a width manually it seems to be square (in the Eclipse Preview Layout Manager) but it ends up outside of the screen and the RadioGroup occupies the entire screen width. If I set a too wide width there is dead space to the right of it.

Tried fiddling with all kinds of settings but nothing gets it quite right. I would like to avoid setting dimensions in absolute values, and rather let the height of the RadioGroup determine the rest of the Views' dimensions...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/MyTabs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weig="1" >

        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />

        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps:
1, Set the layout as below:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/MyTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" 
        ... />

    <RadioButton 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" 
        ... />
</RadioGroup>

<SquareImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

2, Once the view loads, [programatically find the height of linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964499/how-to-get-height-of-linearlayout) and then [programatically set the width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159372/android-view-layout-width-how-to-change-programmatically) of the squareview to this same value to make it a square

3, [Find the width of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height) and then set the width of the radio group to the difference between screen width and above sqaureview width so that it occupies the remaining screen width.

Comment: This almost works, except it breaks when I rotate my phone into landscape mode and then back again into portrait mode. After the second rotation the RadioGroup's width is not changed until I tap some item on the screen (for example a TextView). Not sure why this is the case?