# Move objects over a defined random amount in java

Tags: java, android

So I have this `TextView` in android/java that I would like to position randomly along the horizontal axis where it is located. This is the code I have so far:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp" //This is the width I want to randomize
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/n5"/>
```

My goal is that, by randomizing the `100dp` in the `android:layout_width=` line, I can move my `TextView` over by a certain random amount. Would anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: emm... you want to move something a *defined*, *random* amount? seems you're wanting to do the impossible.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:
1. give the View an id

```
<View android:id="@+id/picture_stream"  
      android:layout_width="100dp"  
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

2. change width programmatically in onCreate:

```
...
View view_instance = (View)findViewById(R.id.nutrition_bar_filled);  
LayoutParams params=view_instance.getLayoutParams();  
params.width=newOne; //use Math.random() to create the value.
view_instance.setLayoutParams(params);
```

See also ["view layout width - how to change programmatically"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159372/android-view-layout-width-how-to-change-programmatically).

You could also use margin/padding instead of "pushing" it with another view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movingTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/n5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Set the TextView as the sole item inside a horizontal Linear Layout and then programatically set a random left padding for the textview.

```
TextView movingTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.movingTextView);
movingTextView.setPaddingRelative((int) 1+Math.random()*100,0,0,0);
```