# Adding Rule programatically to a View that is already in the layout - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layoutparams

How do i add a rule to a View that is already in my layout?

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mylifeinformationsharedsocial.SexAcivity" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add `layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,myView.getId());`
But if i add the View again to the layout it gives me an IllegalStateException(obviously Haha).

So how do i do that?

**EDIT**

Java:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);
listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,datePicker.getId());
relativeLayout.addView(listView,layoutParams);
```

It throws the Exception at the `addView()` method

Comment: Don't use addView, but setLayoutParams. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159372/android-view-layout-width-how-to-change-programmatically).

Comment: @Matthias Thnaks man. i Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add the view cause it's already added. So, you need to set the correct layout params. You can either create new ones or retrieve the current ones and alter those. Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159372/android-view-layout-width-how-to-change-programmatically).

```
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,myView.getId());
listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

So as Matthias suggested:

```
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,myView.getId());
listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```