# Android bottom sheet design

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

Is there any way i can design a bottom sheet fragment as follows:

[image: bottom sheet]

I need to set the width of the bottom sheet to 1/4 of the screen. IS it possible to implement this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same result with [this](https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet) library. Or just make the same [CornerSheetBehavior](https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/CornerMaterialSheetBehavior.kt). As you can see it's just a BottomSheetBehavior with managing of *translationX* of view

Comment: Nice library mate! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout file for your bottom sheet as normal, and set the width to what you need:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sheet_background"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/drag_up_from_here">

        <!-- Bottom sheet contents here -->

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then to get it to stick to the right hand side, you can programmatically append the bottom sheet to your layout. This is how I add my bottom sheets:

```
    val inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val bottomSheet = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_layout, null)
    val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet.findViewById<View>(R.id.drag_up_from_here)

    // Allow user to drag part of bottom sheet
    bottomSheet.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.drag_up_from_here).setOnClickListener {
        if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
        } else {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
        }
    }

    // Create popup window
    val bottomSheetPopup = PopupWindow(popupViewLower,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    false)

    // Get the view you want the bottom sheet added to
    val currentView = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main_view)

    // Display the popup window
    bottomSheetPopup.showAtLocation(currentView, Gravity.BOTTOM, currentView.measuredWidth, 0)
```

The key for getting it on the right of the screen is this part:

```
bottomSheetPopup.showAtLocation(currentView, Gravity.BOTTOM, currentView.measuredWidth, 0)
```

Where currentView.measueredWidth is passed as the x value, moving the bottom sheet all the way to the right.

Edit: I realized you're also asking for the width to be exactly 1/4 the width of the screen. To do this, programmatically set the width of the bottom sheet layout to currentView.measuredWidth / 4. This post explains this well: [Android view layout_width - how to change programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159372/android-view-layout-width-how-to-change-programmatically)

Comment: I appreciate you including an explanation alongside your code and reference. Thank you.