# onClick() event at CardView

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any onClick() event at a CardView?

I didn't find any solution on the web.

Example:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"/>
```

So when I click on the cardview the layout_height goes up to 160dp. Is there any possibility?

Comment: okay thanks i will try it

Comment: i deleted my comment since answers shouldn't be commented and you edited your question to make it more clear. if you want example code, it is below with my answer :) you didn't ask how to set the height of a cardview, so i only included code for what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onClick()` either programmatically or in the `xml` file. Here are them both ways:

In the `xml` file: (Make sure you have a method called `changeHeight` with a parameter of `View view` defined)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:onClick="changeHeight"
            android:id="cardview"/>
```

Notice that I set an `id` for the CardView here. You want to do this if you are going to set an `onClickListener()` programmatically.

Programmatically:

```
CardView cv = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardview); // using the id we set
// earlier.
cv.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    // set the height
});
```

Comment: okay thanks and how do i change the height in java? i thought it could be cardview.layout_height but it doesnt..

Comment: To change the layout_height field, you can have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159372/android-view-layout-width-how-to-change-programmatically

Basic idea is to have a new `LayoutParams` instance with the `height` value with your desired value and set it to your `CardView` object.